# Why charged particle interaction cross section increases as the particle's energy decreases?

Tags: interactions, protons

I'm tying to gain a little more understanding of the dose deposition profile of high energy (~100MV) protons in matter (depth dose curve - medical physics).

I understand that the [Bragg peak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragg_peak) occurs because the proton deposits most of its energy just before stopping.

I'm wondering why particle interaction cross section is related to the protons kinetic energy. An answer in lay terms would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this [Bethe-Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_formula)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the detailed answer but I think it should be due to the Coulomb type intersection between the charged particle and the absorber. In very lay terms I see faster particles as more slippery. I think I am in the right direction...

Comment: Or simpler, given a force resulting from each "side" interaction, faster particles are deflected less.....

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this behavior as described by [Bethe-Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_formula) is due to [electron pickup](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362618/12568). Which I'm guessing quite literally means the propagation of electrons along the path of the particle by coulomb interaction.

As the particle slows, interaction with electrons is more common because of this build up of electrons

Comment: I think someone can do much better than this