# what is electron pickup in the context of Bethe-Bloch

Tags: particle-physics

what is the definition of electron pickup in the context of high kinetic energy charged particles moving through matter ([Bethe-Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_formula))?

Answer (score 1):

Heavy charged particles (nuclear fragments) tend to pick up electrons as they travel through the medium. Therefore they behave as particles with a charge that is smaller than the charge of the nuclear fragment itself. As they slow down, the particles pick up more and more electrons, and the energy loss decreases rather than increases.

Comment: Thats counter to bethe block.

Comment: But we are not really talkimg about heavy particles, but rather individual electrons for instance

Comment: Sorry... individual protons